# issue in adding elements into a list in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm trying to create an online examination system. Here, in my controller i'm taking a Question object from the Razor view, including the selected answer and I need this answers to be added into a list.
this is my controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(QuestionLoadDTO ques)
{
    List<string> answersList = new List<string>();
    int count = 0;
    count = int.Parse(Request["qid"].ToString());
    count++;
    string selectedAnswer = ques.selected.ToString();
    answersList.Add(selectedAnswer);
    if (count <= 4)
    {
        IQuestionService ser = new QuestionService();
        QuestionLoadDTO q = ser.GetIndividualQuestions(count);
        return View(q);
    }
    Session["msg"] = answersList;
    return RedirectToAction("Submit");
}
```

QuestionLoadDTO:

```
public class QuestionLoadDTO
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string QuestionDes { get; set; }
    public string selected { get; set; }
    public string Answer1 { get; set; }
    public string Answer2 { get; set; }
    public string Answer3 { get; set; }
    public string Answer4 { get; set; }    
}
```

Submit Razor View:

```
@{
    //ViewBag.Title = "Submit";
    var list= Session["msg"] as IEnumerable<string>;
}

<h2>Submit</h2>
<div>Submit</div>

@foreach (var item in list)
{
    <div>@item</div>
}
```

I'm not able to add all the answer elements in. It just adds only the last answer elements.
(at the moment i just have only 4 questions in my database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are creating a new `answersList` for every POST request. You need create the list once and store it in `Session`.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(QuestionLoadDTO ques)
{
    List<string> answersList = null;
    if(Session["answersList"] != null)
        answersList = Session["answersList"] as List<string>;
    else 
    {   
        answersList = new List<string>();
        Session["answersList"] = answersList;
    }
    int count = 0;
    count = int.Parse(Request["qid"].ToString());
    count++;
    string selectedAnswer = ques.selected.ToString();
    answersList.Add(selectedAnswer);
    if (count <= 4)
    {
        IQuestionService ser = new QuestionService();
        QuestionLoadDTO q = ser.GetIndividualQuestions(count);
        return View(q);
    }
    Session["msg"] = answersList;
    return RedirectToAction("Submit");
}
```

Comment: @Dayan, sorry, did it too hastily. You need to store the list in session for the first time. Check the code now.